# estimated population around a point qgis

Tags: qgis, population

I have a shapefile with points distributed in a polygon. The points are post office locations within a census district. How can I estimate if the post office is a representation of the concentration of population in this area recently settled (1870-1890)? Can I do any geo-statistic? Regression? Txs

Answer (score 1):

There is a tutorial here [Spatial analysis tutorial](http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/02/tutorial-spatial-analysis-points-in.html?m=1) that shows you how to perform a similar task to that which I think you are trying to do.

I hope this is useful.

Comment: Txs. I've already followed that tutorial and was useful to find how many points I have but the question is more complicated. Can I estimate concentration of population around points? Is there any way to do that?

Comment: @Gus: If your polygon only has a total for population in it and you have multiple points which are the Post Offices, which as I read your question is the case then I think you have a problem as you don't appear to have census data broken down any further than your one polygon. It would appear that the best you can do is calculate X Post offices per head of population. To do what you appear to be after would require a further breakdown of population numbers to smaller polygons. Does your census data contain smaller sub divisions of area that you could be make into smaller polygons?

Comment: yes that was my first idea. I do have some population records from some towns and my first guess was to estimate the distance of the post office to the town and estimate the population. My main concern is with rural post offices as with urban (or sort of in 1880s) can broadly estimate it. As I'm new to GIS I imagined that it was some stat plugin which could do the math.